# Как сделать бота в дискорде без метки "бот"?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Нужно сделать бота на сервер для отправки сообщений через определённое время.
Но прикол в том что все боты с пометкой "**бот**".
Можно ли убрать эту метку и как?

Comment: Убрать  нельзя .

Comment: Но ведь есть спам боты без метки.

Comment: Регать реальный акк и управлять им, а не через ключи работать. Очевидно же.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Только автоматизация обычного аккаунта противоречит правилам и грозит баном этого аккаунта.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Это уже другая сторона медали. Понятное дело, что те акки без пометки, о которых он говорит, тоже нарушают.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Ну, это и напоминание ТСу, что боты должны быть ботами, а не прятаться. К тому же именно поэтому у Дискорда нету открытого описания API пользователя, только для бота.

Comment: @Геннадий П Ну если забить на правила, то как автоматизировать акк

Comment: @Бродяга Вряд ли тут будет дан ответ, если рассматривается вопрос в таком ключе

Comment: @Бродяга Готовый фреймворк для клиентского API вряд ли просто так получится найти в инете. Можете попробовать отреверсить протокол сами, например веб-клиента. Отличий от API для бота не думаю что много, главное авторизацию правильно реализовать.